# Build an AssetBundle runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bundle, assetbundle

I'm using Unity and I need a button that calls a function that allows me to build an AssetBundle, so I can make a software external from unity that allows me to build AssetBundle; is it possible?
Thank you all.

Comment: It is possible, but it's really hard with reverse engineering, see this [Global Illumination on an unprecedented scale](https://youtu.be/D7LjsabD4V4?t=28m31s) talk at Unite Europe 2017. And it obviously not officially supported and the format can change with any Unity Update.

Answer (score 0):

> Build an AssetBundle runtime

This can not be done. bulding assetbundles requires the [buildPipeline](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildPipeline.html) which is in the [UnityEditor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UnityEditor.html) namespace which can not be accessed at runtime as it is editor only.

Making an external application for this that you call from within Unity would most likely also not work unless you know how to replicate their pipeline in your own application, and i doubt you will be able to call it form outside Unity (And even if you could it would still not work at runtime as assets will become read only)

I'm not sure why you would want to build assetbundles at runtime, but the only method i can think of that may work for this would use JSON/XML.

This would need two Instances of unity running to do it in "real time". The first instance of unity would be running your game with the object you want to make into anassetbundle. After clicking your button a function would be called that gets all the information on your GameObject (components, values, ID's, literally everything) and parse it into a XML/JSON file. This file will then be uploaded/saved somewhere where your second Unity instance can access it. The second instance of unity will then read this JSON/XML file in editor time, reconstruct the original GameObject from the data within (This can be done in editor time from script) and then put this reconstructed object through the assetbundle pipeline.

Do take note though that i've never done this myself, and am not 100% it will work. Though i am fairly confident if done correctly it should work.